# Can 3d rotations of functions with parity symmetry be mapped to a plane with real projective plane boundary conditions

Tags: rotations, projective-geometry, spheres

If I have function $f(\theta,\phi)$ such that $f(\theta,\phi)=f(\pi-\theta,\phi+\pi)$, then can this function be mapped to $\mathbb{R}P^2$, say on a square with appropriate boundary identifications such that rotations of the function on the sphere are mapped to translations on the plane?

Answer (score 0):

When can define $\Bbb RP^2$ as $[0,\pi]^2 /\sim$, where $(0, \phi) \sim (\pi, \pi - \phi)$ and $(\theta, 0) \sim (\pi - \theta, \pi)$ (and everything else is equivalent only to itself). So we must have $f(0,\phi) = f(\pi, \pi - \phi)$ and $f(\theta, 0) = f(\pi - \theta, \pi)$ for $f$ to push forward to $\Bbb RP^2$. This is the only requirement. Any $f$ defined on $[0,\pi]^2$ that satisfies those two equations pushes forward to a map $\hat f$ on $\Bbb RP^2$. And if $f$ is continuous, then so is $\hat f$.

If $$f(\theta,\phi)=f(\pi-\theta,\phi+\pi)$$
then setting $\phi = 0$ gives exactly $f(\theta, 0) = (\pi - \theta, \pi)$. Setting $\theta = 0$ gives $$f(0,\phi) = f(\pi, \phi + \pi)$$which requires that $$f(\pi,\pi-\phi) = f(\pi, \phi + \pi)$$Unlike the other equation, this doesn't correspond to the requirement for $f$ to push forward. But note that it doesn't contradict it either. If $\phi \in [0,\pi]$, then $\phi + \pi \notin [0,\pi]$, so it doesn't matter what the value of $f(\pi, \phi + \pi)$ is.

So as long as your function $f$ also satisfies $f(0,\phi) = f(\pi, \pi - \phi)$, it will push forward. If $f$ does not also satisfy this condition, it doesn't push forward.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If $f$ satisfies these requirements then can rotations in $S^2$ (of such a function) be mapped to translations in $\mathbb{R}P^2$? Basically I am trying to write some code that can take convolutions of these kinds of functions but I would like to do them on a plane with boundaries appropriately identified.

Comment: Okay, I missed the part about the sphere in your question. This leaves me unsure as to what you are thinking. $\Bbb RP^2$ can be constructed from both the sphere and the square, but the ways in which this is usually done are not compatible. Is $f$ supposed to be a function on the sphere with $(\theta, \phi)$ the regular spherical coordinates?

Comment: Basically what I have is a scalar for each line through the origin, actually many such functions (indexed by $k$); $F_k : \mathbb{R}P^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, what I was wondering is if there is a way to do cross-correlation of these functions on a plane. But now, after some reflection I think this is not possible because $\mathbb{R}P^2$ as manifold is actually curved and if I do naive translations on this plane I am distorting the function. In your opinion is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need them defined over the whole plane? The construction of $\Bbb RP^2$ I gave comes with a map $\pi : [0,\pi]^2 \to \Bbb RP^2 : p \mapsto [p]$ where $[p]$ is the equivalence class of $p$ under $\sim$. If $f : \Bbb RP^2 \to X$ for any set $X$, then $f\circ \pi : [0,\pi]^2 \to X$ is called the *pullback* of $f$ to $[0,\pi]^2$. Any function $g : [0,\pi]^2 \to X$ is the pullback of a function on $\Bbb RP^2$ if and only if $g$ satisfies $g(0,\alpha) = g(\pi, \pi - \alpha)$ and $g(\alpha, 0) = g(\pi - \alpha,\pi)$ for all $\alpha \in [0, \pi]$.

Comment: I think I will re-ask this question being more clear.